# Компиляция mozjpeg (Windows)

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер!

Для компиляции [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/tree/dctrellis) использую MSYS2.
Параметры компиляции

```
cd /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/mozjpeg-dctrellis
autoreconf -fiv
./configure
make
```

Вот что выдает.

```
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o): In function `jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_mmx':
jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o): In function `jsimd_extrgb_ycc_convert_mmx':
jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o): In function `jsimd_extrgbx_ycc_convert_mmx':
jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0x73c): undefined reference to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o): In function `jsimd_extbgr_ycc_convert_mmx':
jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0xa9c): undefined reference to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o): In function `jsimd_extbgrx_ycc_convert_mmx':
jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0xe2c): undefined reference to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
simd/.libs/libsimd.a(jccolmmx.o):jccolmmx.asm:(.text+0x118c): more undefined references to `GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:832: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «libjpeg.la»
make[2]: *** [libjpeg.la] Ошибка 1
make[2]: выход из каталога «/c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/mozjpeg-dctrellis»
Makefile:1950: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all-recursive»
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/mozjpeg-dctrellis»
Makefile:713: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

При этом, если я компилирую так, то все работает:

```
cd /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/mozjpeg-dctrellis
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"
make
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на проблемы в самой mozjpeg-dctrellis.
При сборке со следующим флагом проблем при сборке не возникает.

```
./configure --without-simd
```

При сборке через cmake этот флаг установлен?
Почему используешь именно этот бранч а не master?

Comment: при master тоже самая ошибка. А как посмотреть значения cmake?

Comment: В выводе cmake должно быть видно, там должно фигурировать слово SIMD.

Comment: -- Building i386 SIMD extensions. Вот что выдает

Comment: Это какая-то проблема в скриптах configure. Возможно создатели даже не проверяли такой метод сборки в MSYS, при этом cmake всё делает правильно. Чем не устраивает сборка через cmake?

Comment: Мне надо скомпилировать https://github.com/fhanau/Efficient-Compression-Tool , внутри него mozjpeg. Если посмотреть Makefile, то компиляция идет через ./configure. Вот и пытаюсь решить

Comment: Могу лишь посоветовать добавить в Makefile ECT флаг --without-simd. В этом случае она собирается без проблем согласно инструкции.

Comment: Благодарю за совет! так и сделаю